# Do distinct eigenvalues produce linearly independent eigenvectors even if they eigenvalues are scalar multiples of each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a real 4x4 with $det(A)=0$ and eigenvalues $-4, -2, 7$ and I need to explain why $A$ is diagonalizable. I know that if $det(A)=0$ then the constant term of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $0$ so $0$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$, which gives me 4 eigenvalues of A. I know that if those 4 eigenvalues are linearly independent that A is diagonalizable since I'll have a real 4x4 matrix with 4 linearly independent eigenvectors but I'm unsure of my reasoning since it hinges on the assumption that distinct eigenvalues produce linearly independent eigenvectors. I know distinct eigenvalues produce linearly independent eigenvectors but -4 and -2 are scalar multiples of each other and I'm not sure if that would mean they have the same eigenvector or if the fact that they are distinct factors of the characteristic polynomial means that they have different eigenvectors.

Comment: The scalar field you're working with (I assume) is the real numbers, so all of your eigenvalues are scalar multiples of each other (except perhaps 0).  So sure, $-4 = -2\times 2$, but you also have $7=-4\times (-7/4)$, and $-7/4$ is just as much a scalar as $2$ is. As long as the eigenvalues are not equal then their associated eigenvectors will be linearly independent, i.e. their eigenspaces will intersect only at the zero vector.

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi I see, thank you!

Comment: It does not make sense to call eigenvalues linearly independent.